# How to get `Info-mode`'s text to horizontally fit the window like in the html version?

Tags: window, formatting, info, scaling

See images for a comparison. The emacs version line-wraps much before the horizontal space ends. Html version was screenshotted from [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Replying-to-the-sender-of-a-message.html)

[image: emacs]

[image: html]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer is that you can't (without a *lot* of work). Info text is hard-filled to a particular width (number of chars per line).

You can, however, use command `text-scale-adjust`, bound by default to `C-x C-0`, `C-x C-=`, `C-x C--`, `C-x C-+`, to zoom the text in or out, till it fits your window width as you like. Or press and hold `Control` while using the mouse wheel to do the same thing.

Or once you know the overall text-scaling factor you want, just use `(text-scale-set FACTOR)`.  You can put that in your init file, adding a function that does that to `Info-mode-hook`.